Looking for specific travel training gear (finger strength for climbing)
I am looking for specific portable finger training equipment for climbing and am not sure if this exists or is something that I should make myself. The general idea is a portable hangboard, but instead of hooking it to a wall, I want to hook it on my foot, so I can practice finger strength everywhere. I would prefer to have it made from lightweight wood as well, with the connecting rope non-elastic.
For more context, I do not mean a rubber finger exercise trainer, as this generally trains the opposite motion of what I am talking about.
I can update with some more details if necessary.

Welcome Geigercounter. Unless someone can definitively say something along the lines of "you need to make one yourself" or "here's a generic example, plenty available from retailers", this may be closed as it looks a lot like a shopping request, which are off-topic here because details on items change and shop webpages are very much subject to link rot.

Hi bob1! Thanks for the comment. The reason I came here is because I've been searching for quite a while for this specific type of training gear, but I haven't found anything yet. I would be quite surprised if nothing like this exists though, so I am wondering if it might be something a bit more common in climbing circles in other countries. Moreover, if it doesn't exist I would definitely be interested in hearing why it might generally be a bad exercise? Hopefully this gives some more details, but if it's still off-topic, I'm happy to delete!

This is rather common and exists in both commercial and DIY versions, with or without pulling force indication, and so on. Principle is often called 'no hang' training because, well, you don't hang, but is also known under different names. The board itself is typically called 'mini fingerboard' or 'portable hangboard'.
Overall it is considered to have the same effect as hangboard protocols for finger strength, though the secondary (as in: not the target ones for training) muscles involved are somewhat different.
Here's a DIY version: a scale + a mini hangboard for the edge. The latter is pretty easy to make yourself as well if you have basic woodworking skills.
